# Writing a parser for a DSL in OCaml using ppx and extension point

Tags: ocaml, camlp4, ppx

Recently, it was announced in OCaml official github that `Camlp4` is replaced by `ppx rewriters and extension points` (https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4):

> Camlp4 was part of the official OCaml distribution until its version
>   4.01.0. Since then it has been replaced by a simpler system which is easier to maintain and to learn: ppx rewriters and extension points.

I have been using `Camlp4` to write parsers for DSL (separated syntax from OCaml).

So, I would like to ask if the `ppx rewriters` tool can do the same thing?

Thank you for taking time to read my question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  PPX is specialized to extend OCaml language functionality keeping its syntax, possibly using attributes and extension points.  It does not provide a parser generator like CamlP4.  If you are building a syntax completely different from OCaml, just stick to P4.  PPX does not help you.

CamlP4 is not discontinued.  It became an independent tool of OCaml compiler: https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4  You should also be able to install it using `opam install camlp4`.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer! It clears out my doubt about Camlp4 and PPX!